# spring-ws-core and apache cxf based service

Tags: spring, web-services, jboss, jetty, cxf

I have a webservice.
in which i am using`2.7.6 version for cxf and 2.1.0.RELEASE` for `spring-ws-core`.
Everything works fine on `jetty`.
But when i move to DEV environment where we use `jboss` it gives following exception
I've did some googling and found out that it could be because of version changes.
but that didn't help me.
do anybody else has experience with this that what versions could solve my problem if it because of version.
Your help is appreciated as always.Thanks

```
415 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (main) Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.<init>(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;)V
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:321)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
                at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
                at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
                at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
                at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
                at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
                at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
                at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
                at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
                at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
                at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
                at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
                at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
                at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
                at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
                at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
                at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
                at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
                at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
                at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
                at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
                at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
                at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.<init>(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;)V
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
                at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.getBus(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:63)
                at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:54)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
                ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.<init>(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;)V
                at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.setApplicationContext(SpringBus.java:87)
                at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:106)
                at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:85)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
                ... 91 more
2014-09-10 10:25:34,417 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/nextgen-ind-pds-webservices-cbv2]] (main) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.<init>(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;)V
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:321)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
                at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
                at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
                at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
                at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
                at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
                at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
                at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
                at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
                at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
                at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
                at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
                at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
                at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
                at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
                at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
                at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
                at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
                at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
                at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
                at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
                at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
                at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.<init>(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;)V
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
                at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.getBus(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:63)
                at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:54)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
                ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.<init>(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;)V
                at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.setApplicationContext(SpringBus.java:87)
                at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:106)
                at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:85)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
                ... 91 more
2014-09-10 10:25:34,418 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (main) Error listenerStart
2014-09-10 10:25:34,418 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (main) Context [/nextgen-ind-pds-webservices-cbv2] startup failed due to previous errors
2014-09-10 10:25:34,418 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/nextgen-ind-pds-webservices-cbv2]] (main) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2014-09-10 10:25:34,423 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/nextgen-ind-pds-webservices-cbv2 state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/apps/server/pds-client/tmp/aa3d11-ou13ob-hzwtiay7-1-hzwtjzfq-b9/nextgen-ind-pds-webservices-cbv2.war/ deployment failed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276054/error-creating-bean-with-name-cxf-defined-in-class-path-resource-meta-inf-cxf)

Comment: @Jens I've tried your link. But its not helpful for me.
Even after changing spring-ws-core latest version it didnt' work.

Comment: Why would you need spring-ws-core when using Apache CXF? I don't really get that part. Apache CXF isn't related to Spring WS nor the other way around.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using spring-ws-core because this service is a client(using webservicetemplate). for an other service.